# Excel Userform export to access

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

is there any limitation on how many textboxes allowed on userform used to export data to Access database?

```
rst.AddNew
For i = 2 To 7
rst(Cells(1, i).Value) = Me.Controls("Arec" & i).Value
Next i
rst.Update
```

Above code works just fine but when i increased the number of textboxes in the userform and the field of the Access database accordingly,error occurs (3265)

Answer (score 0):

Could it be because the one of the field names doesn't exist in the recordset? The cause for this error might be something simple, like an extra space or similar.

Comment: i am sorry if this sounds stupid but when i went through the codes, what i understand was if i were to use loop like above code, the name of the field in the access database does not matter. is that wrong?

Comment: No, it doesn't sound stupid at all. I'll try to recreate the error on Monday. By the way, how do you get the data in row 1? If by import from access, then I'm most likely wrong here. If not, that might be worth checking